# HHVM WSOD (white screen), no errors for SOME pages

Tags: php, nginx, debian, hhvm

I have try to move from Apache + cli_php to NGINX+HHVM(3.8) on Debian.
The problem is HHVM couldn't load some includes (/var/www/site/inc/inc.php).

```
/var/www/site/index.php
             /inc/inc.php
```

Browser error is 502 Bad Gateway.

I tried to set these options in `server.ini` with no luck. Does it make any sense?

```
hhvm.sandbox.directories_root = /
hhvm.source_root = /
hhvm.sandbox.home = /
hhvm.server.always_use_relative_path = false
```

nginx:

```
server {
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/site;
        index index.php;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        include hhvm.conf; #standard 3.8
}
```

In addition, did I mention right that in error messages HHVM remove first part of the include path before actually site-root?

Comment: My guess is that it views `/var/www` as root. Can you make a `/var/www/index.php` containing `echo __DIR__`?

Comment: I made `/var/www/site/test.php` with `echo __DIR__` and access to it via `example.com/test.php`. I get `/var/www/site`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in DOS endline characters. Look like HHVM doesn't interpret it right. In browser you get 502 Bad Gateway error, but terminal hhvm error is `file not found`. Also strange -- if there is echo output in that included file -- problem disappear.

So I convert included file with dos2unix and problem has been solved.

To find out all php files and convert it to unix-style, run this in the root directory of the site:

```
apt-get install dos2unix    
find . -name "*.php" -exec dos2unix {} \;
```